# Using "Microsoft Surface Keyboard" on Mac Sierra

Tags: mac, keyboard, microsoft

I know the Microsoft Surface Keyboard isn't compatible with the lastest Mac OS. But was wondering if anyone has found workarounds to some of these problems.

1) It's not recognized as a keyboard but a bluetooth device. And I have to re-pair the keyboard everytime after long idle period or computer restarts.

2) I am able remap command/option keys using Karabiner-Element, but now the function row doesn't work at all. And with Karabiner turned off, I can use some of the built in function keys such as brightness/volume controls but can't seem to remap them with something like Keyboard Maestro.

I enjoy the feel and travel distance of the keys, and would be nice to have this keyboard working fully and help those that feel the same.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely correct about function key row: with the keyboard's function key lock engaged, the F1, F2, etc functions do work. However, unlocked none of the functions (volume, play, etc) work nor can they be mapped with Karabiner-Element.

This is pretty much par for the course for any Microsoft keyboard used on an Apple